# Mi dominio ya se propago, pero no me muestra mi sitio web - Interplanet

Tags: php, hosting

He compara un plan de dominio y Hosting en la compañía de **Interplanet** ya mi dominio se propago pero no se porque motivos no me esta mostrando mi sitio web cuando entro al directorio raíz de mi proyecto. No se si es porque tengo que esperar mas tiempo o tengo que hacer algo o tal vez es porque tenga algún error y no me estoy dando cuenta.

La verdad es que si alguien tiene experiencia en este asunto, me vendría bien una ayudadita.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: Imagen del directorio raíz del proyecto]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy intentado hablar con el soporte de **Interplanet**, pero dicen que ahora están ocupados y tengo la mañana antera intentando comunicar con ellos y nada. Me urge solucionar este problema.
Un saludo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No parece que tengas instalado ningun servidor web ahi.. puede ser?

Comment: No es claro cómo tienes montado tu sitio en el hosting... es difícil decir qué pasa. Puede que no tengas arriba un servidor web o que no hayas habilitado lo que sea que desees servir por ese dominio. Lo que es claro es que no tiene nada que ver con que el dominio esté resolviendo en los DNS. Claramente está llegando a lo que tu hosting está sirviendo

Comment: Saludos. Verifica que tu archivo (digamos) principal se llame `index.php` y que este (en tu caso que muestra) dentro de `bomgos`. Esto claro, sí y solo sí ya subiste el sitio completo mientras te atienden.

Comment: ¿Cuánto tiempo hace que abriste el dominio? La propagación total suele durar un máximo de 48 horas. Verifica tu dominio con [esta web](https://dnsmap.io). El dominio puede ser visible en unos países primero que en otros según la propagación, ahí te dará un reporte completo sobre el estado del dominio.

Comment: @A.Cedano Compre el plan hace aproximadamente unas 15 o 17 horas, esta mañana me levante y corrí a buscar mi dominio en Internet y solo aprecio como lo enseñe en las capturas. Ya configure la base de datos ayer mismo y si, tengo mi index.php dentro del directorio raíz. Voy a actualizar la pregunta para colocarlo

Comment: El archivo `index.php`  debería estar directamente dentro de `public_html` a no ser que quieres que la dirección de tu dominio sea: `www.bomgos.com/bomgos` Para probar, crea un archivo `index.php` con algo como esto: `<?php echo "Hola mundo"; ?>` y luego accede a `www.bomgos.com`, deberías ver en pantalla `Hola mundo`

Comment: @A.Cedano Hice lo que me dijiste y funciona. Dice "Hola mundo" sin problemas, que crees que este pasando ?

Comment: @A.Cedano [Visitala](http://bomgos.com/)

Comment: A mi no me muestra nada. Lo que **estaba** pasando es lo que te expliqué antes, **tenías tu archivo `index.php` en el lugar equivocado**. Ese archivo debe estar en `public_html` no en una subcarpeta `bongos`

Comment: @A.Cedano Amigo, resulta que he colocado todos los archivos de `public_html` pero ahora sigue sin mostrarme el sitio. algo estaño sucede con esto

Comment: ¿Qué significa *«he colocado todos los archivos de public_html»*? Empieza por algo sencillo, que es creando un archivo `index.php` en `public_html` que diga `Hola mundo` y cuando funcione organiza los archivos como quieras. Lo que debe quedarte claro es que `index.php` debe ir en `public_html`. Luego, si tu sitio estará bajo Wordpress u otro CMS deberás hacer redirecciones a través de `.htaccess` según te indique el CMS que uses.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110990/discussion-between-braylin-ivan-payano-and-a-cedano).

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo he resuelto, el problema estaba en que tenia la conexión a la base de datos incorrecta, estaba colocando un usuario incorrecto y una contraseña incorrecta.
Gracias a todos ustedes por ayudarme, ya lo he solucionando